# Trigger does not work but there is no error message

Tags: apex, trigger, code, developer

I have a trigger that is supposed to work like this "If an account has a case attached to it with a Customer Save record type then the LE_Status__c field on the account is updated to "Red".  It is not working and I assume it has something to do with the account query, but I'm not sure what is wrong. Here is the trigger.

```
Trigger UpdateLEStatus on Case (after insert) {
    Set<Id> UpdatedCaseIds = new Set<Id>(); 

    Id recordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.RecordTypeInfosByName.get('Customer Save').RecordTypeId;

    for (Case c: Trigger.new) {
        if (c.RecordTypeId == recordTypeId) {
            UpdatedCaseIds.add(c.id);
        }    
    }
    List<Account> AccountForUpdating = [SELECT LE_Status__c
                                                       FROM Account
                                                       WHERE Account.Id IN: UpdatedCaseIds];
    for (Account item: AccountForUpdating) {
        item.LE_Status__c = 'Red';
    }
    update AccountForUpdating;
}
```

Comment: You can just use **WHERE Id IN :** instead of Account.Id.

Answer (score 3):

Your UpdatedCaseIds holds case ids and your select is filtering Accounts based on these ids which will not return any! You need to create a UpdatedAccountIds set..

```
Trigger UpdateLEStatus on Case (after insert) { Set UpdatedAccountIds = new Set();

Id recordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.RecordTypeInfosByName.get('Customer Save').RecordTypeId;

for (Case c: Trigger.new) {
    if (c.RecordTypeId == recordTypeId) {
        UpdatedAccountIds.add(c.accountid);
    }    
}
List<Account> AccountForUpdating = [SELECT LE_Status__c
                                                   FROM Account
                                                   WHERE Account.Id IN: UpdatedAccountIds];
for (Account item: AccountForUpdating) {
    item.LE_Status__c = 'Red';
}
update AccountForUpdating;
```

Comment: when I tried this it gives me an compile error and I'm wondering what I did wrong. I am new to development. typically I'm on the admin side. Do you have any guidance? Thank you

Comment: What is the error? You may need to change some of the fields to match your schema.